# Hash function property

Tags: hash

Let $H$ be a hash function that is both hiding and puzzle friendly. Consider $G(z) = H(z) \Vert z_l$ where $z_l$ is the last bit of $z$. Show that $G$ is puzzle frielndly but not hiding.

This question is from [this](https://d28rh4a8wq0iu5.cloudfront.net/bitcointech/readings/princeton_bitcoin_book.pdf#page=50) book, page 50). I'm stuck at proving $G$ as non-hiding.

> A hash function is hiding if: when a secret value $r$ is chosen from a
>   probability distribution that has a high min-entropy, then given
>   $H(r \Vert x)$ it is infeasible to find $x$.

Now for given function $G$, we have:

$G(r \Vert z) = H(r \Vert z) \Vert z_l$

I don't see how $G$ fails to be hiding. If we are given $G$'s output, we just know about one fixed bit of the input. $H(r \Vert z)$ (the part of the output excluding the last bit) still makes it infeasible to determine $z$ since $H$ is hiding. How can one bit of input prevent $G$ from hiding?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What if the input $x$ is only one bit? Would not $G$ leak all of $x$?

In otherwords, the hiding property should work for all plaintext spaces, even if your plaintext space is $\{0,1\}$. $G$ is not hiding for that plaintext space.

Comment: So am I right in understanding that if input's sufficiently large, $G$ still holds the hiding property?

Comment: @abhink, but the typical definition of a hash function is that it should be able to hash anything. That said, even if the input is 2 bits $\{00,01,10,11\}$, then it would be hiding. If you know the last bit of the input, you would be able to throw out two of the 4 possible inputs, but you would not know which of the remaining it was (beyond any *apriori* information about distributions about the inputs).